# Clover Java heap space error

Tags: java, maven, jvm, out-of-memory, clover

I am getting java heap space error while running from hudson and I set my `MAVEN_OPTS` as below, any body can let me know what is the resolution for this issue.

```
-Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=3000m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m
```

```
 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Java heap space
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Trace`enter code here`
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.BitSet.initWords(BitSet.java:144)
        at java.util.BitSet.(BitSet.java:139)
        at com.cenqua.clover.InMemPerTestCoverage.(InMemPerTestCoverage.java:66)
        at com.cenqua.clover.CloverDatabase.mergePerTestCoverage(CloverDatabase.java:494)
        at com.cenqua.clover.CloverDatabase.merge(CloverDatabase.java:437)
        at com.cenqua.clover.CloverMerge.mainImpl(CloverMerge.java:36)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugin.clover.CloverAggregateMojo.mergeCloverDatabases(CloverAggregateMojo.java:260)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugin.clover.CloverAggregateMojo.execute(CloverAggregateMojo.java:79)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor.executeMojo(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:182)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:65)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:185)
        at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:165)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1005)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:936)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 87 minutes 35 seconds
    [INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 21 12:20:13 PDT 2011
    [INFO] Final Memory: 112M/3123M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    channel stopped
    Publishing Clover coverage report...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to my experience, the -XX:MaxPermSize should not be equal to the -Xmx.
On the other hand, it is a subset permanent memory inside the -Xmx.

I've found that the 50% may be good enough. Anyhow we need to monitor the GC 
for ensuring if it is configured properly or not.

```
e.g.
-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.